# What is this manga about hair cutting?

Tags: beauty-pop

There is a shoujo manga I remember reading probably about six years ago (give or take) about a school with a hair cutting club in it. There are a few boys in it (maybe 3) and they are essentially celebrities within their school. They do hair cutting shows for the school in the auditorium, and they turn the girls from being unattractive to being very attractive. They may have also done makeup for the girls as well.

There was a girl in the manga who had been trained by one of the master hair cutters (her father) but she didn't like cutting hair. She ends up getting involved in it, however, and she's very good at it. I think in the manga book covers she had pink or orange hair. Does anyone know what manga this was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]  [image]

The manga you are looking for is called "Beauty Pop".

Here is [MAL's synopsis](http://myanimelist.net/manga.php?id=633):

> Although a truly gifted hairstylist, Kiri Koshiba has no interest in using her talent to pursue fame and fortune, unlike the three popular boys in the "Scissors Project" at school. Determined to become the best makeover team in Japan, they give showy makeovers to handpicked girls. As much as Kiri tries to shy away from the Scissors Project spotlight, she finds herself responding to beauty's call